# jest fails to parse tsx

Tags: unit-testing, next.js, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a frontend project built on nextjs+reactor, and jest is used to test the **pure js code** of the nodejs part（es5 module）.When I try to use jest for testing the react code of the frontend part, I found that jest cannot parse the tsx file:

```
nextjs-test/__tests__/unit/src/Card.test.tsx:50
                component = react_test_renderer_1.default.create(<Card_1.default />);
                                                                 ^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

jest.config.js looks like:

```
module.exports = {
  clearMocks: true,
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageDirectory: "coverage",
  coverageProvider: "v8",
  moduleDirectories: [
    "node_modules"
  ],

  moduleFileExtensions: [
    "js",
    "jsx",
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "json",
  ],

  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$': '<rootDir>/__tests__/unit/__mocks__/file.ts',
    // identity-obj-proxy 
    '\\.(css|less)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
  },

  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  transform: {
    "^.+\.tsx$": 'ts-jest',
    // "\\.[jt]sx?$": "babel-jest",
  },
};
```

and the .babelrc is:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["next/babel", {
      "preset-env": {
        "modules": false,
        "targets": {
          "browsers": [
            "IE >= 11"
          ]
        },
        "useBuiltIns": "entry"
      }
    }],
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "targets": {
        "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ],
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "declaration": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es5",
      "es6"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.js",
    "src/**/*.jsx",
    "__tests__/**/*"]
}
```

When I changed transform config to using babel-jest another error occur：
jest.config.js

```
  transform: {
    "\\.[jt]sx?$": "babel-jest",
  },
```

```
    import React from "react";
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1505:14)
```

I want to know how to change these configuration files so that jest can run tests for both the node part (es5 module, pure js) and the react part(almost all tsx) at the same time